# Searching vector's upper bound using binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given an input(value1) I need to find its upper bound in a vector("vec"). Instead of returning the upper bound value, I need to return pointer to this upper bound value.

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(5); vec.push_back(7); vec.push_back(15);
```

If my input value1="13",  then my function upperBound() should return pointer to element 15.

upperBound() function returns "pointerUpperBound" -- which is a pointer to the upper bound of value1.

Upper bound in my case means a value which is greater than or equal to the input value (value1). It is the smallest number that is greater than the input

```
 //**GOAL OF ALGORITHM: Given "value1" it needs to find value1's upper bound  in vector "vec". Instead of return the upper bound element, I need to return pointer to upper bound element**
bool upperBound(int* &pointerUpperBound,int value1, vector<int> vec)
    // Perform a binary search
{
   unsigned left=0,right=(vec.size()-1);
   int* l=&vec[0];
   int* r=(l+vec.size()-1); //l will be start of pageInfo vector and r will be end of page info vector
   if(vec.size()==1) //vec has just one element in it.
   {
       pointerUpperBound=l;
       return true;

   }   
   while (left!=right) {
      int* pointerUpperBound=l+((r-l)/2); 
      unsigned middle=left+((right-left)/2);
      if(value> (*pointerUpperBound)) {     
         l=pointerUpperBound+1;
         left=middle+1;
      } else if (!middle) { //reached the upper bound, it is "pointerUpperBound" which is also returned.
         break;
      } else {
         int* prev=pointerToUpperBound;
         prev--;
         if(value1 > (*prev)) {
             break;
         } else{
             right=middle;
             r=pointerToUpperBound;
         }
      }
   }
   // Unsuccessful search?
   if (left==right) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

My algorithm does not return correct upper bounds. Can someone please help me figure out as to where am I going wrong.

I want to traverse this vector using "pointers" only. I dont want to use built-in functions for finding upper bound -- as I want to learn where my algorithm is going wrong.

Comment: what's your function (algorithm) supposed to do?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Given "value1" it needs to find value1's upper bound in vector "vec"

Comment: and then what..? be explicit.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Then it needs to return a pointer (called pointerUpperBound) to the upper bound position within the vector

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Is my question understandable now?

Comment: The term "upper bound" can mean a lot of things. What does it mean in your case?

Comment: @Carlos Upper bound in my case means a value which is greater than or equal to the input value (value1)

Comment: @AlexanderFell you mean the smallest number that is greater than the input or any number greater than input?

Comment: @Carlos You are correct..I mean smallest number that is greater than the input

Comment: Hmm, the algo for that should no be hard. Question is whether it is sorted already, in which case you get logn complexity, or not, in which case you get n complexity.

Comment: It's already been done for you. Read about `std::upper_bound`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't thought through the case that the requested value is greater than anything in the vector, and by ignoring that case you got other cases wrong as well.

You haven't posted the real code you tested because:

```
  int* pointerUpperBound=l+((r-l)/2); 
  unsigned middle=left+((right-left)/2);
  if(value> (*pointerUpperBound)) {     
     l=m+1;
```

What is `m` ??

All that redundant work (pointer and unsigned copy in parallel) is just a source of confusion.  Use one or the other.

Think about your code (after you made the above correction):

```
  if(value> (*pointerUpperBound)) {     
     l=pointerUpperBound+1;
     left=middle+1;
  }
```

If `value > *r` the above code could reach `l=r+1;`  Is that what you intended for that case?  If not, what did you intend?

What case did you think you were covering with the final?

```
   // Unsuccessful search?
   if (left==right) {
       return false;
   }
```

Think about the situation in which `r==l+2` and the answer you want is `r`.  You try location `l+1` and it is too small, so you set `l=l+1+1;` and never try that location because it is `r` but you simply end the loop and return `false`.  You snatch defeat from the jaws of victory.

---

```
bool upperBound(int* &pointerUpperBound,int value1, vector<int> vec)
    // Perform a binary search
{
   int* l=&vec[0];  // Pointer to lowest that might be == value1
   int* r=l+vec.size(); //Pointer PAST last value that might be < value1

   while ( l < r ) {
      int* m=l+((r-l)/2); // Notice m<r, m>=l
      if( value1 > *m ) {     
         l=m+1;  // l always increases here
      } else {
         r=m;  // m always decreases here
      }
   }
   pointerUpperBound = l;  // first position >= value1
}
```

The code is really trivial.  The boundary cases deserve thought, but I think they all work out.  If every item in the vector < value1, this code returns the first position past the end of the vector.  That is a design choice (not right or wrong).  If you don't like that choice, it should be easy to change.

In any binary search, you need care that it always converges, never gets stuck in a loop not changing `l` or `r` when `r==l+1`.  That is a common enough flaw in binary searches that I commented in the code the reasons I think it doesn't happen.

Then you need a precise definition of where `l` and `r` point in order to see whether boundary cases are safe.  `l` passes only elements `<value1` so we remain sure it doesn't pass the first element that might `==value1`.  `r` backs up to items not `<value1` so it might back up across items `==value1` so in the boundary case of multiple items matching `value1` we seem to find the first.  That is an accidental "design choice" you might or might not prefer to change.  But otherwise, we at least see `r` never backs up to an item `<value1`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is really helpful. But I am really not getting how can I correct this code. i.e. how can I design my code such that it takes care of all the cases you are suggesting. Can you please help me with this a bit. I'll be really thankful to you for the same

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to use `pointerUpperBound` as an *output* parameter, but you pass it *by value*.

The caller won't see the modifications you make to the the pointer.

Pass a reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But still do u see any logical error in it...I mean does it seem to be logically wrong in "finding pointer to upper bound value within vector vec"